# Hooks: processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray()

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am about porting an Extention from T3-6.2 to T3-7.6+

```
public function processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(
   &$fieldArray, $table, $id,
   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler &$pObj
) {
    // t3_origuid is set? Yes, ist a Copy
   if(isset($fieldArray['t3_origuid']) && $table=='mytable') {
      $fieldArray['field1']++;
      $fieldArray['filed2']--;
   }
}
```

BUT:

To tell if it is a copy or not this needs the field 't3_origuid' in my record. It is not a standard field but if present it is filled by typo3.

Where does this filed come from? My I use this witout further problems?

If you know a hook/better way, (Slot, Signal?) to use in this case in T3 7.6+ please let me know.

Thanks a lot,

Christian.

Answer (score 0):

This field is used by the sys extension workspace. If you change a tt_content element inside a workspace the original uid will be stored inside the field. So the changes,when they will be published, can be applied to the original element.